# How to detect session creation/termination in the WDM driver?

Tags: windows, session, driver, wdm

I'm building a device driver for Windows (WDM driver, 32 bit), and I need to detect the creation and the closure of the terminal sessions.

I know how to obtain the session ID of the caller process (`ZwQueryInformationProcess` with the `ProcessSessionInformation` flag). I'm also intercepting the event of the graphics driver load/unload into the session (by intercepting `ZwSetSystemInformation` with `SystemLoadImage` / `SystemUnLoadImage`).

And I hoped that session creation/closure event will be followed by the call to `ZwSetSystemInformation` with the `SystemCreateSession` / `SystemDeleteSession` flags. But unfortunately this doesn't happen. So far I didn't find a good indication of the session creation/closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SystemCreateSession` and `SystemDeleteSession` aren't used anymore. I haven't done much investigation into this, but take a look at when the 0x80 flag is set in the ProcessFlags passed to `NtCreateUserProcess`. It may be related to the creation of CSR for each session.